# How to land on a page after a sign out in firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I have created a signout button

```
<input type="button" name="" value="Sign out" id="btn-action" onclick="signout();">
```

Now i am triggering a function signout()

```
function signout(){
document.getElementById('btn-action').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  firebase.auth().signOut();
  alert('Hi');
  window.location='userpage.html';
});}
```

i want that onclicking signout button user must be logged out and page should be redirected to user.html.I tried the above approach but nothing is happening on clicking signout button.Please rectify my error.

Comment: No that alert is not appearing

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49659347/edit) your question to include the proper tags for the language/platform you are using (ios/android/javascript/nodejs/python/numpy/...)

Comment: i have edited @Andre Kool

Answer (score 0):

Your `signOut` function when clicked is adding event to button, but you already clicked on it, so it's waiting for another click.

Instead of adding event inside function, move it out of function:

```
function signout(){
    firebase.auth().signOut();
    alert('Hi');
    window.location='userpage.html';
}
```